# Summing up rewards when encountering terminal state in n-step DQN

Tags: q-learning, dqn

I'm trying to implement n-step DQN using deque for n-step experience buffer and I am not sure how to handle the terminal state in calculation

For step = n = 5, Sx = state number x, T - terminal state, suppose we have in the deque:

```
S1, S2, T, S4, S5
```

Should I count rewards from S1 to S5 or stop counting rewards at T? It would sound logical. However, I have managed to find this [article](https://gibberblot.github.io/rl-notes/single-agent/n-step.html) which comes closely to my question, but some parts of it sound contradictory to me (especially [this](https://gibberblot.github.io/rl-notes/single-agent/n-step.html#:%7E:text=This%20just%20sums,whichever%20comes%20first.) and [this](https://gibberblot.github.io/rl-notes/single-agent/n-step.html#:%7E:text=However%2C%20even%20though,we%20have%20executed.)).

Comment: In your example, how does the experience replay get to store values for $S_4, S_5$ and what do they represent? Are they nulls, repeats of $S_T$, start of the next episode, or something else?